# Is a graph simple, given the number of vertices and the degree sequence?

Tags: graph-theory

Does there exist a simple graph with five vertices of the following degrees?

(a) 3,3,3,3,2

I know that the answer is no, however I do not know how to explain this.

(b) 1,2,3,4,3

No, as the sum of the degrees of an undirected graph is even.

(c) 1,2,3,4,4

Again, I believe the answer is no however I don't know the rule to explain why.

(d) 2,2,2,1,1

Same as above.

What method should I use to work out whether a graph is simple, given the number of vertices and the degree sequence?

Comment: The answer to a, and for d are in fact yes.

Comment: Why, for example, do you believe that 2,2,2,1,1 is not possible? Simple sketching should show that it is possible, in more than one way.

Comment: @yaakov How do I know this? Is there a given property that tells me this?

Comment: not as far as I know. I just took a pen and paper, and searched naively.

Answer (score 5):

The answer to both a, and d, is that in fact such graphs exit. It is not hard to find them.
The answer for c is that there cannot be such a graph - since there are 2 vertices with degree 4, they must be connected to all other vertices. Therefore, the vertex with degree one, is an impossibility.

Answer (score 3):

(a) 3,3,3,3,2   - YES!  [Graph Justifies claim](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n1Jvn.png)

(b)1,2,3,4,3   - NO -Follows from the **[Handshaking Lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Handshaking_lemma)**

(c)1,2,3,4,4   - ANYBODY? (has no problem by Handshaking Lemma)

(d)2,2,2,1,1  - YES! [Graph Justifies Claim](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pOIqQ.png)

Comment: for case (c) There can not be a vertex with degree less than 2. Let me explain this. There're **two vertices with degree 4** (i.e have edges from all remaining vertices). So, each other vertex should have **at least** two edges incident on them (from the above two vertices with degree). So there can not be a vertex with degree 1. I think I'm clear. Answer is **NO**.

Answer (score 1):

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degree_%28graph_theory%29 or google for "degree sequence". I have only seen Havel-Hakimi theorem before, but wikipedia also mentions other results.

Answer (score 1):

a.) Apply Havel-Hakimi:

$$
\begin{align}
& 3,3,3,3,2 \\
\to & 0,2,2,2,2 \\
\to & 2,2,2,2
\end{align}
$$

Since the sequence $2,2,2,2$ is graphic (it is the degree sequence of $C_4$), then the original sequence is graphic.

c.) Reorder and apply Havel-Hakimi:

$$
\begin{align}
& 4,4,3,2,1 \\
\to & 0,3,2,1,0 \\
\to & 3,2,1
\end{align}
$$

Since the sequence $3,2,1$ is not graphic (a graph on 3 vertices can have maximum degree of 2), then the original sequence is not graphic.

d.) Apply Havel-Hakimi:

$$
\begin{align}
& 2,2,2,1,1 \\
\to & 0,1,1,1,1 \\
\to & 1,1,1,1
\end{align}
$$

Since the sequence $1,1,1,1$ is graphic (it is the degree sequence of $K_2+K_2$), then the original sequence is graphic.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Handshaking lemma and the Havel-Hakimi algorithm to solve these problems.  [Here is a link to a powerpoint on it](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=7&ved=0ahUKEwillIbwkdLUAhUs_IMKHdQPDHIQFghJMAY&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.dcs.gla.ac.uk%2F~pat%2Faf2009%2FmySlides%2FHavel-Hakimi.ppt&usg=AFQjCNHFAOO_WoLj4-SNQqy5x79xYtEsUg&cad=rja).

Basically, it goes like this (using the degree sequence [3 2 2 1] as an example):

1. If any degree is greater than or equal to the number of nodes, it is not a simple graph.
2. Handshaking lemma: if the number of vertices with odd degrees is odd, it is not a simple graph.
3. Order the degree sequence into descending order, like 3 2 2 1
4. Remove the leftmost degree: 2 2 1 , and call the first degree k, so k=3 here
5. Subtract 1 from the leftmost k degrees: 1 1 0
6. If any of the degrees are negative, it is not a simple graph.
7. Go back to step 3 and repeat 3-7 until we find it is not a simple graph, or all degrees are 0, or we reach another situation we know it is a simple graph (like a cycle with 2 2 2 ...).

In the case of 3 2 2 1, we would do it like this

3 2 2 1

2 2 1 <- intermediate step (4), do not apply the handshaking theorem here yet

1 1 0 <- after step 5; this is a simple graph, so we stop here and find that 3 2 2 1 is a simple graph.

## (a)

So for your (a), it would be

3 3 3 3 2 <- looks good through steps 1 and 2

3 3 3 2 <- step 4

2 2 2 2 <- step 5, subtract 1 from the left 3 degrees.  Now we have a cycle, which is a simple graph, so we can stop and say 3 3 3 3 2 is a simple graph.  Or keep going:

2 2 2

1 1 2

1 1

0 0 <- everything is a 0 after going through the full Havel-Hakimi algo, so yes, 3 3 3 3 2 is a simple graph.

## (c)

4 4 3 2 1

4 3 2 1

3 2 1 0 <- looks good after one iteration through havel-hakimi

2 1 0

1 0 -1 <- negative degrees aren't possible, so we know that 4 4 3 2 1 is not a simple graph.

## (d)

you should be able to draw (d) pretty easily.  2 vertices connected as a pair, and 3 in a cycle.